# How does rsync with daemon works?

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to sync files from a source machine to a destination machine in the same local network. These machines have less cpu speed. As far as I read in some domcumentations ist that rsync with daemon is less cpu hungry than using it over ssh.

The Question is: Where do I have to start the daemon, on the source or the destination machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daemon is on your source machine, you have only server configured on this one.
Then, all destination machines will sync with him.